# Mudblazor: MudDataGrid KeyBoardNavigation

Tags: c#, datagrid, mudblazor

it is possible to override the default Keyboardnavigation in a MudDataGrid?

With pressing tab-key we want to get to the next row in the same column instead of getting to the next column in the same row.

[image: grid image]

Can somebody help me please?

Best regards,
Hageböller